# How to set title for Navigation Bar

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uikit

How to set the title on a root viewcontroller inside a navigation viewcontroller.  
Generically, the answer seems to be, "set self.title of some viewcontroller".  but this only works for the viewcontrollers I am pushing to.  On the initial viewcontroller, running 
`self.title = @"my title";` or `self.navigationController.navigationItem.title = @"my titles";` don't work.

Thinking that is needed to be set earlier on, I did this in app delegate:

```
   MainMenuViewController *mainMenuViewController = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
   mainMenuViewController.title = @"coding chal";
   self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainMenuViewController];
```

What must I do for the root viewcontroller to have a title?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am using a xib for the view, so no storyboard.  Can it be as easy as overriding the default init?

Comment: I am indeed calling `initWithNibName`, I have overridden `initWithCoder` but it is never called.  And is there a rationale for setting title and navigationItem.title?

Comment: anyway, i tried overriding `initWithNibName` which **does** get called but setting those two properties you mentioned fails to render the title

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121446/discussion-between-user5797668-and-matt).

Comment: Please don't delete your questions once you've received a good answer. We've received some complaints about this, and I've undeleted two of these.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the view controller's `title` does work. When you run into trouble, the best course is make yourself a minimal test example. Here's one. This is the only code in the app!

In the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [UIWindow new];
    ViewController* vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController* nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

In the view controller:

```
- (instancetype) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    self.title = @"Testing";
    return self;
}
```

Result:

[image]

So you can see that it really does work. If it seems not to work in your app project, therefore, that must be because of *other* code somewhere.

Comment: Well, presumably you have other code that screws things up. I know nothing about that. I think I've proved that this works. What do you want me to do, email you the project?